# In a uniformly accelerated motion experiment, the acceleration can be attained from $V_{ave}$ vs. $t/2$ and $x$ vs. $t^2$ graph. How is this possible?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, time, velocity, data-analysis

Specifically, in the experiment, we had to release a glider from an inclined plane (that had an angle of inclination of 10 degrees). We had to calculate the time it reaches the final position. We had to calculate the average velocity from the five trials we had to do for each distance (50cm, 60cm, 70cm, 80cm, 90cm, and 100cm). After this, we had to plot in the values in a x vs y graph.

[image]

[image]

I am just confused as to why time in the first graph is divided by 2, and how the graph's slope is equal to the acceleration of the particle in the experiment. Why is Vave plotted against t/2 instead of just t? In the first graph, what does a non-zero y-intercept value mean?

As for the second graph, I am confused as to why time is squared, and how the graph's slope times 2 is equal to the acceleration of the particle in the experiment.

I've been stuck with these questions for days now, and I still couldn't figure it out. I'm very curious what the right answers are to these questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an object is moving at constant acceleration then its position and speed are described by a set of five equations known as the suvat equations. The one we need to use here is:

$$ s = ut + \tfrac12 at^2 \tag{1}$$

where $t$ is the time, $a$ is the acceleration, $u$ is the initial speed and $s$ is the distance travelled. In your experiment you are starting the object from rest so $u=0$, and the equation simplifies to:

$$ s = \tfrac12 at^2 \tag{2}$$

This immediately explains your second graph, because if we graph the distance $s$ against $t^2$ we get a straight line going through the origin with gradient $\tfrac12a$. Your fit doesn't quite go through the origin, but this is likely to be experimental error.

To explain your first graph note that the average speed is the distance travelled divided by the time taken:

$$v_{av} = \frac{s}{t}$$

If we take equation (2) and divide both sides by $t$ we get:

$$ \frac{s}{t} = v_{av} = a~\left(\tfrac12 t\right) $$

So if we graph $v_{av}$ against $\frac12t$ we get a straight line through the origin with a gradient of $a$.

Comment: And the two gradients are, as expected, almost in the ratio of two.